# storing value into a variable from a returned function in TCL

Tags: tcl

I have a function that returns a string however I cant store that value into a variable. I tried doing this

```
% set m [return "This is returned value"]
This is returned value
% puts $m
can't read "m": no such variable
```

Any suggestions what I might be doing wrong here ?
Also I tried something like this

```
% set m [puts "Test"]
Test
% puts $m
...
```

the output of m is blank why is that ?

**Update :**

After looking into this issue. It seems that I have a method that cannot be altered. This method prints an output to the screen. What I want to do is to capture that output in a variable as well.

Comment: "returned function"? I don't see where you return a function. `puts` returns the empty string. Use `return` to return a value.

Comment: I answered “capturing stdout” pretty recently over at http://stackoverflow.com/a/27350274/301832

Answer (score 5):

If you want to return value from a function it should something like this

```
proc value { } {
   return rajesh
}

set result [value]
```

`puts` command won't return any value and it will be empty string if you assign it to a variable.

In your first case, you have used `return` inside the variable assignment like

`set m [return "This is returned value"]`

Because of `return`, code will return immediately. It has nowhere to return to. Further code below this of any, won't run at all. That's why the it got failed as 
`can't read "m": no such variable`

Comment: use `set m [return -level 0 "This is returned value"]`